# Spark array of arrays: how to extract first element of each subarray (structtype)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming dataframe column that contains an array of arrays, like:

`[[ts1, url1], ... , [tsN, urlN]]`

where each subarray is a struct:

```
schema_visits = StructType(
   fields = [
      StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True),
      StructField("url", StringType(), True),

])
```

and N is variable from row to row.

What I'd like is to get a column with urls only:

`[url1, ... , urlN]`

I think I could use explode(), getItem("url") , groupby+agg+collect_list to achieve that, but I wonder if there is simpler way?

Since it's Structured Streaming,  udf are probably not going to work, but if they are, that would be interesting as well.